# Xamarin.iOS -AppleLanguages argument

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to use -AppleLanguages "(de)" launch argument to specify system language on simulator when using Xamarin.iOS? This is very handy when testing internationalized apps. This argument works perfectly when launching app (written in Swift) from Xcode. VS for Mac has run configurations and it is possible to pass arguments there but neither -AppleLanguages nor -AppleLocale doesn't work.